# How to reassign the value of a column that has repeated values if it exist for some value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'codes': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'results': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', None, None, None, None, None, None]})
```

I need to produce the following:

```
   codes results
0      1       a
1      2       b
2      3       c
3      4       d
4      1       a
5      2       b
6      1       a
7      2       b
8      1       a
9      2       b
```

It is guaranteed that if the value of `results` is not `None` for a value in `codes` it will be unique. I mean there won't be two rows with different values for `code` and `results`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with `merge`

```
df[['codes']].reset_index().merge(df.dropna()).set_index('index').sort_index()
Out[571]: 
       codes results
index               
0          1       a
1          2       b
2          3       c
3          4       d
4          1       a
5          2       b
6          1       a
7          2       b
8          1       a
9          2       b
```

Or `map`

```
df['results']=df.codes.map(df.set_index('codes').dropna()['results'])
df
Out[574]: 
   codes results
0      1       a
1      2       b
2      3       c
3      4       d
4      1       a
5      2       b
6      1       a
7      2       b
8      1       a
9      2       b
```

Or `groupby` + `ffill`

```
df['results']=df.groupby('codes').results.ffill()
df
Out[577]: 
   codes results
0      1       a
1      2       b
2      3       c
3      4       d
4      1       a
5      2       b
6      1       a
7      2       b
8      1       a
9      2       b
```

Or `reindex` | `.loc`

```
df.set_index('codes').dropna().reindex(df.codes).reset_index()
Out[589]: 
   codes results
0      1       a
1      2       b
2      3       c
3      4       d
4      1       a
5      2       b
6      1       a
7      2       b
8      1       a
9      2       b
```